# scale image and button orientation correctly for landscape and portrait mode ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview, landscape-portrait

Developed a ipad application which looks good in portrait mode.Like following:[image: portrait mode]

But, not looking good in landscape mode.
[image: Landscape mode]

How to make this correct? I have autolayout option enabled...

Note: I'm adding back ground iamge as

```
self.view.backgrounfcolor = [UIColor colorwithparttenimage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ems.png"]];
```

Comment: 1st Setup for the Uiorientation . 2nd Change their frame according to the Orientation OR Create two Views Load accordingly

Comment: "1st Setup for the Uiorientation . 2nd Change their frame according to the Orientation" -> How to do this.pl provide me example code or any link

Comment: Check this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: @Kalpesh, I was refering this, but did not get any help form this.

Comment: if you want to do it programatically then use this method -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

Comment: @bapi : Check out my answer. that is not the way to give answer . But can't explain you from scratch over here ..sorry.. You just need to understand the way , How it works..

Answer (score 0):

Here is just for reference . just copied and pasting from my repository . Change accordingly .

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [self orientationChanged:(UIInterfaceOrientation)[[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation ]];

}

-(BOOL) supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}

-(void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    [self orientationChanged:toInterfaceOrientation];
}


-(void) orientationChanged: (UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation{

    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
        NSLog(@"Changed Orientation To Portrait");
       // self.viewPortrait.hidden = NO;
     //   self.viewLandscape.hidden = YES;
         [self portraitOrientation];
    }

    else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        NSLog(@"Changed Orientation To Landscape");
        //self.viewPortrait.hidden = YES;
        //self.viewLandscape.hidden = NO;

         [self landscapeLeftOrientation];
        /*
         if(deviceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
         NSLog(@"Changed Orientation To Landscape left");
         [self landscapeLeftOrientation];
         }else{
         NSLog(@"Changed Orientation To Landscape right");
         [self landscapeRightOrientation];
         }
         */

    }

}
-(void)landscapeLeftOrientation{

    // Rotates the view.
    NSLog(@"LandscapeLeft");

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
    self.view.transform = transform;
    // Repositions and resizes the view.
    CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
    self.view.bounds = contentRect;
    self.view.bounds = contentRect;

    self.img.center = CGPointMake(256, 23);
    self.btnHome.center = CGPointMake(437.0f, 23.0f);
    self.messageList.frame = CGRectMake(54, 54, 405,200);
    self.txtMessage.frame = CGRectMake(26, 262, 355, 30);
    self.btnSendMsg.frame = CGRectMake(399, 262,61,32);
}

-(void)portraitOrientation{

    // Rotates the view.
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
    self.view.transform = transform;
    // Repositions and resizes the view.
    CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    self.view.bounds = contentRect;

    self.img.center = CGPointMake(160.0f, 24.0f);
    self.btnHome.center = CGPointMake(277.0f, 24.0f);
    self.messageList.frame = CGRectMake(3,49, 341,321);
    self.txtMessage.frame = CGRectMake(3, 378, 235, 30);
    self.btnSendMsg.frame = CGRectMake(256, 378,61,32);

}
```

Comment: @bapi : Check out my answer. that is not the way to give answer . But can't explain you from scratch over here ..sorry.. You just need to understand the way , How it works